# Efficient evaluation of sums

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

This is a programming question.

Imagine that I have $9$ numbers stored as a tensor $N_{ij}$, with $i,j\in[-1,0,1]$. I want to compute the $6$ sums

$$S_{pq}=N_{ij}i^pj^q$$ with $p+q\le2$. Namely,

$$\begin{align}S_{00}&=N_{--}+N_{-0}+N_{-+}+N_{0-}+N_{00}+N_{0+}+N_{+-}+N_{+0}+N_{++}
\\S_{10}&=-N_{--}-N_{-0}-N_{-+}+N_{+-}+N_{+0}+N_{++}
\\S_{01}&=-N_{--}+N_{-+}-N_{0-}+N_{0+}-N_{+-}+N_{++}
\\S_{20}&=N_{--}+N_{-0}+N_{-+}+N_{+-}+N_{+0}+N_{++}
\\S_{11}&=N_{--}-N_{-+}-N_{+-}+N_{++}
\\S_{02}&=N_{--}+N_{-+}+N_{0-}+N_{0+}+N_{+-}+N_{++}\end{align}$$

For efficiency of the computation, some partial sums can be reused. For example,

$$N_{--}+N_{-0}+N_{-+}$$ appears in both $S_{00}$ and $S_{20}$.

The 2D case is manageable and can be solved by hand, with $21$ additions/subtraction.

---

Now I want to extend this to 3D and 4D, keeping the quadratic constraint ($p+q+r+s\le2$). This corresponds to $10$ sums of $27$ numbers and $15$ sums of $81$ numbers respectively.

My question is: what is a systematic way to organize the computation to keep a minimum number of additions/subtractions and *without mistakes* ? (Can be by hand of by program.)

Comment: While the question is interesting, the misuse of the term "tensor" and bastardization of Einstein's summation convention raises my hackles. I do wish we had another name for a multi-dimensional array so that the meaning of tensor would not be so weakened.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: I am not surprised by this purist's reaction.